# How To Use Caching In Dojo?

Tags: caching, dojo

**What I am Doing?**

I have Dojo widget which has call to server. From that Http request it gets list of product code . These product codes are shown in Filtering Select drop down.

**What problem I am facing**

I want to do caching of those product codes so that server request is not raised every time. Product code list is quite large (10 K product codes) so cookie is not good option

Is there any way to do caching in Dojo ? Any learning resource would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried to use [Dojo Cache](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/Cache.html)

Comment: Do you need to keep this cache for multiple visits/sessions? Or just while user stays on one page?